# how to insert toaster/snackbar inside one div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular2-mdl

I have seen a snackbar in getmdl.io.but the snackbar is absolutely positioned at the bottom of the page like this[image]

[Snackbar component in getmdl.io](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#snackbar-section)But how can i place the snackbar inside one div?

Comment: I was also searching for the same one

Comment: http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/snackbar uses getmdl.io styles. the snackbar is positioned fixed so it's always fixed to the browser window. If you want to change this you need to change the style and put the dialog-outlet in the div. the div must be positioned relative and you need to change the animation. In fact the snackbar follows the material design rules. so I would suggest creating your own component and don't use the snackbar for your use case.